# A* how to calculate G cost

Tags: c#, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, a-star

I read this article: [http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm), but i don't understand how is calculated G cost. I know those child's on corner of his parent have bigger score but there is probably another calculation to check distance from current to start node.

Please help.

Comment: This question is offtopic on SO. Try http://cstheory.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the article,
It was stated that G=10 if you move horizontal or vertical and
G=14 if you go diagonal from one square to another square.

Hence if you move horizontal from start square **G = 0+10**
where initially G is 0. Then you move vertical or horizontal from there implies **G=10+10**
and if diagonal means **G=10+14**